# How to make an nested draggable list like an figma layer section?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drag-and-drop, draggable

Need that feature for my project , but I had no idea how ? I already made the simple normal draggable , and it work just fine , but I can't drag to make it nested like figma does

here is my normal draggable Javascript code :

```
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

draggables.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart',() => {
        draggable.classList.add('dragging')
    })
    draggable.addEventListener('dragend',() => {
        draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
        
    })
})

container.addEventListener('dragover', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const beforeElement = getBeforeElement(e.clientY);
    const dragging = document.querySelector('.dragging');
    if (beforeElement) {
        container.insertBefore(dragging,beforeElement.nextElementSibling)
    } else {
        container.insertBefore(dragging,container.firstElementChild);
    }
})
function getBeforeElement(y) {
    const draggableElement = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list-item:not(.dragging):not([data-active="false"])')]
    return draggableElement.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
        const offsetAbove = y - (box.top + box.height / 2);
        if (offsetAbove > 0 && offsetAbove < closest.offsetAbove) {
            return { offsetAbove: offsetAbove, element: child}
        } else {
            return closest;
        }
    }, { offsetAbove : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY}).element;
}
```

If you not understand about what I mean figma layer , here is the link you can see on the left sidebar , there is an layer section , and each item is draggable and can be nested

[figma](https://www.figma.com/file/gPlyzFiqY2RVJuEg2xO1Qo/Free-Icon-Pack-1600%2B-icons-(Community)?type=design&node-id=2-27&mode=design&t=VHhfdBdGypgQnvFX-0)

I want the code with explanation , or if you had an reference you can send me , I really had no idea how to make it , wasting hours but no result..

Comment: Maybe you provide with more code in order to be able to reproduce the example on our side.